# Non ascii characters displayed in a wrong font

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, truetype

I'm trying to use a 'Nilland-SmallCaps' font in my new website. The problem is that while all other text is displayed correctly, specific characters of my language (š, č, ž (s,c,z with caron)) are displayed in default font. I opened .ttf file in a font editor and I found out that these characters were defined, so I don't have a clue why they don't display correctly. If you have an idea on how to fix this, please help me, as I have tried everything I came up with.

```
@font-face {  
font-family: 'Nilland-SmallCaps';  
src: url('Nilland-SmallCaps.ttf')format('truetype');  
}
```

I'm using this font-file: [Nilland-SmallCaps](http://fontzone.net/font-download/Nilland-SmallCaps/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nilland-Smallcaps font is odd in many ways. It does not actually contain small caps, to begin with. But what matters here is that it is not properly encoded. It does not contain glyphs as assigned to locations corresponding to Unicode numbers, except for some characters like the Ascii range.

If you analyze the font using [DTL OTMaster](http://www.fontlab.com/font-utility/dtl-otmaster/dtl-otmaster/) Light, you can see that e.g. the letter š is properly placed, Unicode number U+0161, but the letter ž is assigned to U+0014, which is all wrong, since this is a control character position. The letter č is in position U+E054, which is in the Private Use Area, which should only be used by agreement between interested parties, and browsers aren’t interested. In fact, you can fool (at least some) browsers into rendering č in the font by using the character reference `&#xe054;`, but this is really a horrendeous kludge.

I suggest that you try and find some other, more properly encoded font.

Comment: My employer wants me to use this specific font. I'm no expert at this, but is it possible to edit the font file in a way that would correct these problems?

Comment: Technically, it is possible to edit font files, but you would need the font author’s permission (which you could well get); just being a free font does not imply right to modify the font.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the font-face did not have a custom language setting turned on when the font-face was generated.  Please see a fix here:

[Font Face not working for custom language characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307628/font-face-not-working-for-custom-language-characters)

> The following Font Squirrel options must be selected in order for the
>   correct language glyphs to be generated:
>
> Click on the Custom Subsetting radio buton and selected the following
>   options:
>
> Character Encoding -Mac Roman Character Type -Selected all checkboxes
>   in this section Language - English, French, OR WHATEVER LANGUAGE